# Visual studio - dotless.compiler

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, dotless

I need from file "*.less" create "*.css" file with standart CSS logic before build.

I tried drop `dotless.compiler.exe` at folder and at Pre-Build event call this command

```
$(SolutionDir)content\folder\dotless.compiler.exe -m 
$(ProjectDir)content\css\site.less $(ProjectDir)content\css\site.css
```

but get exception "`command exited with code 3`". Where am I wrong? Can you offer another way?

Comment: Did you check all the files and executables are in place correctly?

Comment: I think that all is okay

Comment: What is the working directory in your case? maybe that's the issue?

Comment: @Tigraine: I'm having the same issue, any idea? $(SolutionDir)\packages\dotless.1.3.0.0\Tools\dotless.compiler.exe -m "$(ProjectDir)\Assets\Styles\Debug\*.less" "$(ProjectDir)\Assets\Styles\Release\*.css"

Comment: Does the compiler generate any output in the site.css files? 
Because to me the syntax looks fine .. you could try omitting the output file parameter so the compiler uses it's built in default of site.css but other than that this looks fine.. 
Do you do anything fancy with imports that may break due to working directory problems?

Answer (score 6):

I've found two common instances where I've received that error code when using the dotless compiler in a prebuild event. The first is if the css files already exist within source control and are locked. The second is when a space (or special character) exists in the file paths to the .less or .css files

This can be fixed by deleting the css file prior to running the compile, and putting all filepaths in quotes:

```
del "$(ProjectDir)content\css\site.css"
"$(SolutionDir)content\folder\dotless.compiler.exe" -m "$(ProjectDir)content\css\site.less" "$(ProjectDir)content\css\site.css"
```

Answer (score 3):

I was also getting error -3. My problem was that my files were under source control and were locked so the compiler could not overwrite css file. 
So, your problem might also be that your css file that needs to be overwritten is locked.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help with the exception from the Pre-Build event, but in the past I've used [chirpy](http://chirpy.codeplex.com/) to generate css files.

I've also used [squishit](http://www.codethinked.com/squishit-the-friendly-aspnet-javascript-and-css-squisher), which generates the css at runtime, as opposed to build/compile.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on windows 8.1 and VS 2013. None of the suggest solutions helped me.

Then I run the dotless compiler explicitly on the CMD as administrator and it worked!